# In the early 20th century, was there any difference in the size of war horse between heavy cavalry and light cavalry?

Tags: military, 20th-century, cavalry

In the early 20th century(during WW1), was there any difference among the sizes of war horses used by heavy cavalry (dragoons, schweres reiters, cuirassiers) and light cavalry (hussars, uhlans, chasseur à cheval) in the countries Austro-Hungarian Empire, France, Imperial Germany?

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: There are significant differences between various national militaries. What country are you particularly interested in? For example, by 1914 the British had nearly eliminated the lance even as the German Empire adopted it wholesale.

Comment: [A reference on British Cavalry 1800-1914](http://www.katetattersall.com/hussars-dragoons-the-glorious-british-cavalry-of-the-mid-1800s/) "*By the 1870s all the British cavalry regiments were carrying sabres, carbines and pistols, and some retained lances.*" and "*Interestingly, all German cavalry regiments took up the lance, and carried them into WWI (1914-18), and the French Cuirassiers were still wearing armour at the start of that horrific conflict.*"

Comment: After WWI, cavalry functions change radically, so we're really only talking about a 15 year period.  I haven't researched the topic, but quick discussion with my professional equestrian consultant confirms that the two have different constraints, and therefore will probably use different horses (even if they are not forced to do so by tradition, which is often more important than physics)   You might check cavalry manuals e.g. [Cavalry Manual](https://www.amazon.com/Cavalry-Manual-Horsemanship-Horsemastership-Gordon/dp/0385016476) in the respective languages as a start.

Comment: During WWI, Imperial Germany cavalry are all lance cavalry, grouped together, I guess they might have same tactics, equipments and so same hands tall horses, and three kinds of Austro-Hungarian Empire cavalry have the same equipments and so probably have the same hands tall horses.

Comment: But I am not sure, I guess after Skirmisher's Line Tactics widely adopted the heavy horses might not be needed for they are generally using for break up the crowd of line infantry in the old time.